# Long running methods from Java SDK for testing purposes

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency

I'm working through some tutorials and examples of java.util.concurrent package. Usually example authors put a placeholder marked with a comment 'long running task'. Since these examples are about concurrent programming I'm not keen of using Thread.sleep(long), surrounded by try-catch blocks.

What do you use in these circumstances?

To open an url, do some complicated float math, i/o... Optimally these long running tasks do not have any side effects.

These methods can be seen as Loren Ipsums on the timescale.

---

I'll add here concrete implementations:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class LongRunningTasks {
    public void triggerKeyGeneration(int iterations) {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                KeyPairGenerator keyGen =
                    KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
                SecureRandom random =
                    SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
                keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
                keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            }
            System.out.println("triggerKeyGeneration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final int SCALE = 10000;
    private static final int ARRINIT = 2000;

    /**
     * http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Digits_of_pi_calculation#Java
     * 
     * @param digits - returns good results up to 12500 digits
     * @return
     */
    public String piDigits(int digits){
        StringBuffer pi = new StringBuffer();
        int[] arr = new int[digits + 1];
        int carry = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= digits; ++i)
            arr[i] = ARRINIT;

        for (int i = digits; i > 0; i-= 14) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
                sum = sum * j + SCALE * arr[j];
                arr[j] = sum % (j * 2 - 1);
                sum /= j * 2 - 1;
            }

            pi.append(String.format("%04d", carry + sum / SCALE));
            carry = sum % SCALE;
        }
        return pi.toString();
    }

    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private static final BigInteger veryBig = new BigInteger(1200, rand);

    public BigInteger nextProbablePrime() {
        return veryBig.nextProbablePrime();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are infinitely many slow algorithms available. What is your intent? Do you want to create a tutorial of some sort?

Comment: @kd304 - i believe he is filling in a tutorial where the author left it as 'an exercise for the editor' to generate long running tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've once used a public-private key generator to do something similar. This is a CPU intensive task. Doing it hundreds or thousands of times should give you a considerable delay.

Answer (score 16):

```
BigInteger veryBig = new BigInteger(10000, new Random());
veryBig.nextProbablePrime();
```

Comment: Awesome. This should be marked as answer. It takes ages and can be even reduced to a single-line statement!

Comment: An even shorter form: `new BigInteger(9999, 9, new Random())`

Answer (score 2):

Calculate pi to a very large number of digits.  A quick google brought up [this implementation](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Digits_of_pi_calculation#Java) which should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

If talking about methods which will anyway require a full activity, how about a simple loop running for a specified time ?

```
public void triggerKeyGeneration(int nbSec)
{
    long objectiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + nbSec*1000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < objectiveTime);
}
```

Comment: In the end, it is, but in this case the Thread is active, and no exception to catch

Answer (score 0):

I use I/O (both local and non), and often a long running task have a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here some problems:

- Check if a big number is a prime number (not probable prime)
- [Integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)